# I cannot view and print the contents of a combobox when I select it. The name of the combobox set is printed, but not its content

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, dictionary, tkinter

[image]

**WHAT IS THIS CODE?** This little script is meant to select a tournament and automatically display the teams related to that tournament in the second combobox. The second combobox displays the teams extracted from the `teams` dictionary. Easy!

Subsequently, the aim is to print the articulated preposition (feminine or masculine) relating to the chosen team, thanks to the dictionaries `article_words` and `nouns`. Everything works fine except the team selection which I now explain the problem.

**PROBLEM:** The problem is `subject = "Atalanta"`, because if I manually enter the name of the team, then everything works correctly without any problem. But I want in subject there is the combobox `team.get()` with which I can select any team (in this case Atalanta or Bologna) I tried to write `subject = team.get()`, but I get `Squadra` which is the name of the combobox set with `Key Error: Squadra` (because it does not find the teams but the word of the set)

**WHAT I WANT?** How can I set the combobox team.get() as a subjet in order to print the article of any team I choose in the combobox? (for example by choosing Atalanta or Bologna, and not manually writing "subject =" Atalanta ").

**CURRENT OUTPUT AND OUTPUT I WANT TO OBTAIN?** Currently the output is `dell'Atalanta`, because I insert subject = "Atalanta". I would also like to get `del Bologna` output, so I need to change the subject and assign it the selectable content of the combobox team.get (). The selection of the article (del or dell' ) occurs with the loop and with the article_words dictionary.

**NOTE**: I don't want to write Atalanta in `subject = "Atalanta"`, it was just an example. I want `subject` to be the combobox team, because I need it inside the `for key, value "loop in article_words.items` there is subject that is linked to the combobox team.

Here is the executable code. In the first part there is a small part of the dictionaries I use, in the second part there are the comboboxes and the function:

```
from tkinter import ttk
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *

root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry("400x150")


teams = {
            "Atalanta": {
                "Nome Squadra": "Atalanta",
                "Campionato": "Serie A",
                "Città": "Bergamo",
        },


            "Bologna": {
                "Nome Squadra": "Bologna",
                "Campionato": "Serie A",
                "Città": "Bologna",
        }
   }
       
                      
                 

nouns = {

        "Atalanta": {"genere" : "femminile", "unità" : "singolare", "apostrofo" : "si"},
        "Bologna": {"genere" : "maschile", "unità" : "singolare", "apostrofo" : "no"},
        }



article_words = {
    
            "del" : {
            "genere" : "maschile",
            "unità" : "singolare"
            },
            
            "dello" : {
            "genere" : "maschile",
            "unità" : "singolare"
            },
                      
            "della" : {
            "genere" : "femminile",
            "unità" : "singolare"
            },
                      
            "delle" : {
            "genere" : "femminile",
            "unità" : "plurale"
            },

            "dell'" : {
            "genere" : "femminile",
            "unità" : "singolare",
            "apostrofo" : "si"
            },                
        }


####################

tournament=ttk.Combobox(root, width = 18)
tournament.place(x=15, y=15)
tournament['value'] = ["Serie A", "Serie B"]
tournament.set("Campionato")

def on_tournament_selected(event):
    # Clear the entry boxes: aggiunto io
    team.delete(0,'end') 
    
    req_teams = [] # For all the required teams
    sel_tournament = tournament.get() # Get the tournament
    
    # get the names for selected gender
    for _team in teams.items(): # Go through all the teams in the dictionary
        key = _team[0] # Get the key
        value = _team[1] # Get the value 
        if value['Campionato'] == sel_tournament: # If Tournament of the loop-ed team is our selected tourname, then 
            req_teams.append(key)
    
    team.config(values=req_teams) # Change the values of the combobox

tournament.bind('<<ComboboxSelected>>', on_tournament_selected)

team=ttk.Combobox(root, width = 18)
team.place(x=200, y=15)
team.set("Squadra")

text = tk.Text(root,width=43,height=2)
text.place(x=15, y=50)


#THE PROBLEM IS HERE:
subject = "Atalanta"

article = ""
for key, value in article_words.items():
    if nouns[subject] == value:
        article = key
        break


def print():    
    phrase = f"{article} {subject}"
    text.insert(tk.END, phrase)


button2 = Button(root, text="Print", command = print)
button2.pack()
button2.place(x=15, y=100)


root.mainloop()
```

How can I solve? Can you show me the code I should use please? (with comments alone I might not understand why I'm starting out with Python). Thank you

Comment: I am not sure I fully understand what your are looking for, but I believe you are having an issue getting the value from the ```combobox```. You should add a ```Tk.StringVar``` to the ```combobox```.

Comment: FOR THE READERS: Other responses from other possible readers would also be appreciated. It is better if I have several different opinions. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the value from a combobox you need to attach a variable to it.
First initialize the variable `teamname = Tk.StringVar(value='')`, here I initialized it with an empty string.

Then attach this variable to the combobox, `team.configure(textvariable=teamname)`.

Now when the combobox box value changes, the `teamname` variable will also change.

Now to get the value use `teamname.get()`.

So in the above example this would look like ...

```
from tkinter import ttk
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *

root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry("400x150")


teams = {
            "Atalanta": {
                "Nome Squadra": "Atalanta",
                "Campionato": "Serie A",
                "Città": "Bergamo",
        },


            "Bologna": {
                "Nome Squadra": "Bologna",
                "Campionato": "Serie A",
                "Città": "Bologna",
        }
   }
       
                      
                 

nouns = {

        "Atalanta": {"genere" : "femminile", "unità" : "singolare", "apostrofo" : "si"},
        "Bologna": {"genere" : "maschile", "unità" : "singolare", "apostrofo" : "no"},
        }



article_words = {
    
            "del" : {
            "genere" : "maschile",
            "unità" : "singolare",
            "apostrofo": "no"
            },
            
            "dello" : {
            "genere" : "maschile",
            "unità" : "singolare"
            },
                      
            "della" : {
            "genere" : "femminile",
            "unità" : "singolare"
            },
                      
            "delle" : {
            "genere" : "femminile",
            "unità" : "plurale"
            },

            "dell'" : {
            "genere" : "femminile",
            "unità" : "singolare",
            "apostrofo" : "si"
            },                
        }


####################

tournament=ttk.Combobox(root, width = 18)
tournament.place(x=15, y=15)
tournament['value'] = ["Serie A", "Serie B"]
tournament.set("Campionato")

def on_tournament_selected(event):
    # Clear the entry boxes: aggiunto io
    team.delete(0,'end') 
    
    req_teams = [] # For all the required teams
    sel_tournament = tournament.get() # Get the tournament
    
    # get the names for selected gender
    for _team in teams.items(): # Go through all the teams in the dictionary
        key = _team[0] # Get the key
        value = _team[1] # Get the value 
        if value['Campionato'] == sel_tournament: # If Tournament of the loop-ed team is our selected tourname, then 
            req_teams.append(key)
    
    team.config(values=req_teams) # Change the values of the combobox

tournament.bind('<<ComboboxSelected>>', on_tournament_selected)

team=ttk.Combobox(root, width = 18)
team.place(x=200, y=15)
team.set("Squadra")

text = tk.Text(root,width=43,height=2)
text.place(x=15, y=50)

def printTeam():
    subject = team.get()
    for key, value in article_words.items():
        if nouns[subject] == value:
            article = key
    phrase = f"{article} {subject}"
    text.insert(tk.END, phrase)

button2 = Button(root, text="Print", command = printTeam)
button2.pack()
button2.place(x=15, y=100)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Could you show me the full code too please? I'm away from home now. Later I will try and accept your answer if successful. However I am afraid that since I am new to Python I may not be able to apply your kind answer. If you also write me the complete code I would appreciate very much, that is your answer applied to my code. I'll read later. Thank you

Comment: I have made an edit with the code in your example. Essentially, you can connect a variable to a combobox to later retrieve the combobox value.

Comment: Using tkinter variable is one of the way but it is *optional*.  You cau use `team.get()` to get selected value without any tkinter variable.

Comment: @nikost There are 2 problems in your code. The first is that I get this error teamname = Tk.StringVar (value = "Team")
AttributeError: type object 'Tk' has no attribute 'StringVar'.....The second is that you entered {teamname.get ()} in the phrase, but I needed it in "subject", because I use "subject" also in "if nouns [subject] == value:". I need the team name both in the phrase and inside if nouns [subject]. Maybe, but to solve it just write "subject = teamname.get ()", I don't know. Can you review your code? I'm waiting for your answer. Thank you

Comment: @acw1668 Maybe you have underestimated my problem, or I have not clearly explained what I want to achieve. I've tried using team.get (), but I'm getting an error.

Comment: @Jas_99 sorry, the reason you get that issue is because ```Tk.StringVar``` should have been ```tk.StringVar```. I have a habit of ```import tkinter as Tk``` but clearly you used ```import tkitner as tk``` I have edited the answer to reflect this. I also fixed a spelling error in one of the ```teamname``` variables that was spelled as ```teanmane```

Comment: @nikost This is not the result I want to achieve. Maybe, you didn't understand what I asked for. I clearly wrote "#THE PROBLEM IS HERE: subject =" Atalanta ". I don't want to write Atalanta, it was just an example. I want" subject "to be the combobox team, because I need it inside the" for key, value "loop in article_words.items () "there is subject that is linked to the combobox team. The loop is for changing the article to the team name, but with your" subject "code in the loop it doesn't work. I divide the comment into 2 parts

Comment: @nikost (continuation of the comment above) Read and re-read this example carefully please. For Atalanta, the output is "dell' Atalanta", while for Bologna, the output is "del Bologna". The selection of the article (del or dell' ) occurs with the loop and with the article_words dictionary. With your code, I get "dell' Bologna" which is an error, because the loop to select the article is not applied. So I need "subject" inside the "for key, value in article_words.items ()" loop to be connected to the combobox team. I want to use "subject" also in the loop for key, value in article_words.items"

Comment: @acw1668 Can you help me too please? I would be happy for your answer. The kind nikost has come close to the answer, but there is something wrong with his answer. I would be happy to read your answer as well. Thank you :)

Comment: @Jas_99 If you need to article to update when the subject changes, you can put the loop that looks for the article in a function. Then you can call that function when the print command is made. I will post an update

Comment: I changed my answer to not user ```tk.StringVar```. Additionally I changed the name of the print function so it doesn't override the standard print function. I printed out some values, and the reason you get ```None``` for your article is because you have no matching article dictionary for Bologna. It seems maybe you need to change ```dell'``` to be maschile instead of femminile. Either way, the answer provided should work so long as you fix your dictionaries to match the values.

Comment: @nikost Is the function necessary? If possible, I prefer not to have it. Currently my loop works fine/good with no function. The article (del or dell' ) is changed correctly if I write "subject =" Atalanta ". But Atalanta is just an example. I need subject to be connected to the combobox team. As said the loop to change the article works correctly I just need the possibility to change the selected team to "subject = xxxx". I'm waiting for your answer. If so, I will accept your answer as a solution, because I asked this in the main question. Thank you

Comment: Also based on the question, I believe what you need to do is remove 'apostrofo' :'si' in the Bologna noun entry

Comment: If the block of code that updates the value of article is not in a function, it will only be executed once. Then article will have a fixed value.

Comment: @nikost With your new code the output is "None Bologna". My dictionary for the article is written correctly. I need the apostrophe "si" in the dictionary. For example, if in the previous code, instead of subject = "Atalanta" you wrote subject = "Bologna", the output was "del Bologna". It was correct. So my dictionary is well written. It is your answer which is incorrect. I see that there is still subject = "Atalanta" with the comment "#THE PROBLEM IS HERE:". I appreciate your help, you are kind, sorry to say but there is still some problem in your code.

Comment: @nikost You also changed the way the phrase is constructed. It is different from what I did. I need to build the whole sentence in one line, as I wrote in my code

Comment: FOR READERS: I just need to use subject = teamname.get() (or team.get) or something similar. This way, I can use subject wherever I want and how I want

Comment: @Jas_99 The lines ```#THE PROBLEM IS HERE``` and ```subject = "Atalanta"``` are incosequential. The issue is with your dictionary values not matching. I fixed you ```article_words``` dictionary for you and it now works.

Comment: @nikost True, now it works correctly, but I needed it without function for choosing the article. You've changed my code a little too much. In my initial code there was no function for choosing the article: all the code was outside a function. Could you modify your answer by removing the function of the article and leaving out the loop (no function)? So that the printTeam function receives subject and article differently without function. You have complicated and slightly modified my code. Excuse me and thank you

Comment: @Jas_99 to keep the code closer to the original, I have removed the getArticle function and moved its functionality into the printTeam function

Comment: @nikost the code to search for the article, cannot be placed outside the function as I did? I would need it out

Comment: @Jas_99 as i mentioned in an earlier comment, it must be in a function. If it is not in a function how can the value to article update. When you change the combobox value it calls the printTeam function, so only the lines of code in that function will be executed. Hence, if the search for article is outside of this function, the value of article will not update.